# How to generate DIV based template using Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: psd

Sorry I don't where should I discussed this question as it is related to designing:

Is there any plugin or some thing else technique to create DIV based template using Adobe Photoshop? As Adobe Photoshop has an option to save psd as html format but it is TABLE based.

Comment: when you slice your psd you can choose: save for web and devices and then you can say Photoshop to make an html which puzzles your slices together again. But I think that it will generate a table....

Comment: That was I already focused now I want to ask if it possible to generate DIV based html by Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a heated subject for some people. For me, I've had success with [converxy.com](http://converxy.com)

However, there really is no substitute for knowledge and experience. Not all experience is created equally. I find that I'm most effective when I've studied the materials well. It can sound boring, but going over the HTML, CSS and Javascript specs can be a real time saver in the long run.

This may be elementary to you, but someone might find this useful. Generally, I try to search with the keywords "language reference". So, if I were trying to study CSS3 from cover to cover, I'd google "css language reference", or simply "css reference". Then, study each and every document in the reference manual. Usually, you get a good understanding by going through one or two reference manuals.

Like I said, it sounds boring. But, the truth is, gaining mastery takes work. And, in my opinion, this really is the shortest path. After going through one or two reference manuals, try some tutorials or demos (some practice of applying the knowledge) shortly after. I'm sure you'll find, as I have, that working your way through tutorials is MUCH more productive once you've gone through a reference manual or two.

Hope that helps